# Hawaii et Hawaï

Tags: orthographe, histoire, géographie

J'ai cru comprendre lors de mes recherches sur internet que la bonne orthographe était celle avec le *i* tréma. Pour ma part j'avais l'habitude d'écrire les deux *i*.

J'ai vu sur [le Wiktionnaire](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Hawaii) que les deux *i* étaient en fait une variante. J'aimerais savoir **dans quelle mesure cette variante est-elle correcte et d'où vient-elle ?**

---

Édit : graphique représentant l'utilisation des variantes dans la littérature Française.

[image: Les variantes dans la littérature]

Comment: *Hawaii* correspond à l'orthographe originale en anglais du lieu. Personnellement, je l'ai toujours vu écrit avec *ï*.

Comment: les américains prononcent `Hawa iiiiiiiiii` l'orthographe original avec deux `i` me semble donc plus proche de la réalité américaine alors qu'en français on dit bel et bien `Hawaï` sans accentuer le `i` final plus que ça.

Comment: Un autre débat consiste à se demander si on doit utiliser ou non les noms originaux des pays et villes et là le débat est complexe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[L'orthographe française est Hawaï](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=hawaii&T3.x=0&T3.y=0), mais on retrouve également l'orthographe anglaise *Hawaii*. L'orthographe anglaise est elle-même dérivée de l'orthographe hawaïenne *Hawai‘i*. À Hawaï même, l'orthographe hawaïenne domine.

[Le dictionnaire de l'Académie française](http://atilf.atilf.fr/academie9.htm) ne contient pas d'entrée sous *Hawaii* ou *Hawaï*. Il y a, cependant, une entrée sous *hawaïen* qui se lit comme suit :

> HAWAÏEN, -ENNE (*wa* se prononce *oua*) adj. XIXe siècle. De *Hawaï*, nom polynésien de la plus grande des îles Sandwich.
>   Relatif aux îles Hawaï. *Les ports hawaïens. Le climat hawaïen. Guitare hawaïenne*, voir *Guitare*. Subst. *Un Hawaïen, une Hawaïenne*, personne habitant les îles Hawaï ou qui en est originaire. • GÉOL. *Volcan hawaïen*, volcan dont l'activité est continue et dont le cratère est empli d'une lave bouillonnante qui déborde lors des éruptions. *La « chaudière de Kilauea » est un volcan hawaïen.*

Il n'y a pas d'entrée sous *hawaiien*.

Le coup de glotte (l'apostrophe inversée) est ce qui dicte la séparation des deux *i* dans la prononciation anglaise et le tréma en français. Aux États-Unis, on prononce le *h* initial, on met l'accent tonique sur la deuxième voyelle (le « wai ») et on prononce le *i* final sans accentuation particulière : `/həˈwaɪ.iː/`. En français, la prononciation `/awɑ.i/` est, à mon avis, une des meilleures approximations.

Comment: C'est plutôt l'orthographe **québécoise** d'après ton lien non ?

Comment: @Fractaliste Au Québéc, on parle français. Certes, le vocabulaire et les expressions sont différentes et en l'absence d'espaces fines en typographie, on préfère ne pas mettre d'espace qu'en mettre une pleine, mais la grammaire est la même. L'orthographe est la même. C'est la même langue.

Comment: Merci pour l'ajout des précisions, j'avais cherché dans le dictionnaire de l'académie mais sans succès.

Answer (score 1):

Les américains prononcent Hawahiiii (le i est très accentué presque aspiré); ainsi l'orthographe originale avec deux **i** me semble plus proche de la prononciation américaine.

En français on n'accentue pas le **i** mais on le sépare du **a**, le **ï** a donc tout son sens. Les deux orthographes sont proches et peuvent donc être utilisées sans soucis.